# Puppet how to run all manifests in directory

Tags: puppet

So I have a directory of puppet manifests that I want to run.

Is it possible to do something like:
    include /etc/puppet/users/server522/*.pp
and have puppet run them?

I've tried
    include users::server522::*
and several other variations

I always get an error about puppet being unable to find it.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: So my final solution to this was write a script that would take the directory listing and for each .pp file add an include into the server522.pp file.  Quite annoying that puppet won't include an entire directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my final solution to this was write a script that would take the directory listing and for each .pp file add an include into the server522.pp file. Quite annoying that puppet won't include an entire directory.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do here, and are you sure you're doing it the correct way? To wit, if you have multiple manifests corresponding to multiple servers, you need to define the nodes for each server. If OTOH you're trying to apply multiple manifests to a single node it's not clear why you would be doing that, instead of just using your defined classes. A little more information would be helpful here.

Comment: We are managing our users through puppet manifests for specific servers.  Each user has it's own manifest.  Instead of having to each type manifests name into an include within the init.pp, I just want to do something like include /etc/puppet/users/server522/*.pp and have it include all 5000 manifests.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the point of each user having its own manifest. I would rather create script that would automatically build one manifest file, basing on data from some source, for instance from HEAD of git repository containing CSV file with current list of users.

If you realy want to use separate manifest file for every user you may consider having seprate module for every user:

```
manifests
  default.pp <-- here comes default manifest
  module_for_user_foo/
    manifests/
      init.pp <-- here comes your 'foo' user
  module_for_user_bar/
    manifests/
      init.pp <-- here comes your 'bar' user
```

Now you may copy modules containing manifests.